# How to resolve TableView with css in Titanium Android Emulator

Tags: css, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

xsml file as below its display good in web browser but not showing in Android Emulator.

```
 <Alloy >

        <Window id="readWin" class="bg">
            <TableView id="tableView">

            <TableViewRow class="titlebar"></TableViewRow>  

            <TableViewRow></TableViewRow>

            <TableViewRow>

                <TextField class="serachbar"></TextField>

            </TableViewRow>

            <TableViewRow></TableViewRow>

            <TableViewRow center="center" width="190" height="63">

                <Button class="sbtn" id="subbtn"></Button>

            </TableViewRow> 

            </TableView>       
        </Window>

</Alloy>
```

my index.tss code is like

```
'#tableView':{
separatorColor:'none'
 }

"View":{     
layout:'vertical',
},

".bg":{
    backgroundImage:'images/bg.png',

},

".titlebar":{
    backgroundImage:'images/logo.png',
    width:'339dp',
    height:'71dp',
    top:'140dp'

},

'.serachbar':{
backgroundImage:'images/searchbar.png',
    width:'400dp',
    height:'50dp',
    borderStyle:'none',

},
'.sbtn':{
backgroundImage:'images/btn.png',
    width:'187dp',
    height:'60dp',
    borderStyle:'none',

}
```

my index.js file code is

```
$.readWin.open();
```

bg css is applying at window successfully but tableview data is not showing in Andriod Emulator event its good display in Web Browser. what can be the problem please help

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an old post, but I thought I'd add my 2 cents. First, there's no way we can test this code because we don't have the referenced images. Second, remove all the `dp` references in your code by adding this line to your tiapp.xml `<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>`. Finally, explain what you've tried, and what you're trying to accomplish. Your post lacks a great deal of information that would allow others to help you.